# Корутины в IntelliJ IDEA project Gradle problems

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, gradle

Хочу выполнить простой учебный код в IntelliJ IDEA.

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
import kotlinx.coroutines.GlobalScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

private fun log(msg: String) = println("[${Thread.currentThread().name} $msg]")

fun main(){
    networkRequest()
}

fun networkRequest(){
    GlobalScope.launch {
        log("Making network request...")

        for (i in 1..3){
            delay(1000)
            println("First $i")
        }

        log("First network request made!")
    }
}
```

Разумеется все красным, потому что не добавлены зависимости в проект.

Нахожу свежую версию
org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.1
Иду в File->Project Structure -> Modules

Добавляю новую библиотеку с помощью Maven

Ничего не находит

Возвращаюсь и вижу:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ок, добавляю org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.3

Вроде все хорошо

Но в проекте все по прежнему красное и я не могу импортировать

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
import kotlinx.coroutines.GlobalScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
```

Продолжаем... Пробую добавить корутины в подпапку Main

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вуаля ... сработало

Вроде бы этот дурацкий Гредл побежден.

Ну что, запускаем ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И вот такая вот проблема ...

e: /home/Downloads/Coroutines3/src/main/kotlin/Coroutines3.kt: (1, 8): Unresolved reference: kotlinx

Иду сюда https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52522282/using-kotlinx-coroutines-in-intellij-idea-project
И нахожу рекомендацию попробовать org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm:1.5.0

Но это тоже ничего не дает.

**Вопроса 2:**

1. Что сделать, что бы заработали корутины в Идее?
2. Как работать с Гредлом в Идее. В Андройд Студии все просто, в виде
   XML файла. Есть ли способы добавлять зависимости в Идее так же ? Или
   только через настройки ?

Comment: File->Invalidate caches  - не помогает. Корутины не работают (( Может их убрали ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все оказалось проще некуда.  Добавлял их как API, но они не подключались к запущенному проекту, полагаясь что среда где будет запускать приложение уже будет эта зависимость

Правильно добавлять зависимости в гредл build.gradle.kts

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation(kotlin("test"))
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.1")
}
```

Всем добра !

Comment: Спасибо, добрый человек. Было тоже самое)